# Codeigniter RESTful API Server - XML Error?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, codeigniter, rest

I've read the following topics/tutorials:

1. [Codeigniter RESTful API Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089645/codeigniter-restful-api-server)
2. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814
3. https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

And I still can't figure out why I'm with route problems and XML problems. 
My webservice controller is in the folder `controllers/api/webservice.php`

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH.'/libraries/RESTful/REST_Controller.php';

class webservice extends REST_Controller{

     function get() {
        $data = array();
        $data['name'] = "TESTNAME";
        $this->response($data); 
     }
}
```

In the tutorials **there is no need to add routes**, and in order to receive the XML page error I needed to add the following route or it wouldn't work:

```
$route['api/webservice/get'] = 'api/webservice/get';
```

My structure folder of codeIgniter:

```
 > application
   > config
       rest.php (did not change anything from the GitHub download)
   > controllers
      > api
         webservice.php
         key.php
   > libraries
      > RESTful
         REST_Controller.php (changed line 206 to: $this->load->library('RESTful/format');)
         format.php
```

**From the tutorial**, the following link works without routes:

```
http://localhost/testRestful/index.php/api/example/users
```

Mine only works with route

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/api/webservice/get
```

And I receive the following error:
[image]
It does not say anything else. I can't figure out which file is the error talking about.

Comment: Is that your full controller code?

Comment: @Craig Yes it is. I'm just testing so I've nothing else in my controller.

Comment: I only ask because I am sure we've had this problem before, which was fixed by removed unwanted white space.

Comment: I'm trying to delete empty lines/spaces (in the head of files and bottom) to see if I can find it

Comment: @Craig I've solved the XML issue with this solution https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/issues/219, but what about the routes, do you have any idea why do I need to set them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot write get function if you use REST_Controller.
give that function name `test_get`.

```
class webservice extends REST_Controller{
 function test_get() {
    $data = array();
    $data['name'] = "TESTNAME";
    $this->response($data); 
 }
}
```

Now you can access the page with this link

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/api/webservice/test
```

_get and _post is added end of the function to detect either it is get request or post requerst.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but what about the routes, do I need to create them all? Because in the examples they do not create.

Comment: Btw, in order to XML works (http://localhost/myproject/index.php/api/webservice/test?format=xml) the line `ob_get_clean();` must be added to Format.php `construct method`

Comment: I think if you use the right path you don't need routes.You just need to add _get or _post to every function depending on request.